# private routing v6 react

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router

I am trying to implement private routing to my react web application. I have a login, a sign app and a home page, and i want the user to access the homepage only if he is logged in or signed in. I am using Firebase authentication.
I know that my private route component is wrong but because i am new i don't know how to fix it.
I get the error that currentuser is undefined.

Thank you!

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {

const currentUser = useAuth()
console.log(currentUser.email)

return currentUser ?(
    <Navigate to="/home" />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/signin" />
  );
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
return (

  <Routes>
    <Route restricted={true} path='/signin' element={<SignInSide/>}/> 
    <Route
      path="/home"
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <Home/>
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />

  <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUpside/>}/>
      
  </Routes>
```

**useAuth function in firebase.js**

```
 // Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);

  export function useAuth() {
  const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => setCurrentUser(user));
  return unsub;
}, [])

return currentUser;
}
```

Comment: If currentUser is undefined, it is because your useAuth is maybe not doing what you expect? Can we see it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem.
i needed to use context provider and then wrap the app with it

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();


export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  setCurrentUser(user)
  setPending(false)
});
}, []);

if(pending){
  return <>Loading...</>
}

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider
    value={{
    currentUser
    }}
  >
   {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PrivateRoute` component does not make sense, since it is not using the children prop. You should either redirect to the signin page when you don't have a user, or display the children, when you have a user, isn't it ?
It could look like this :

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const currentUser = useAuth()
    return currentUser ? children : <Navigate to="/signin" />;
};
```

However, your error doesn't come from the router, but rather from your `useAuth` hook it seems. Initially, your user is undefined, so it is normal that you get an error saying this.
If you want to logout the email of the user, try to do the following instead:

```
if(currentUser)
  console.log(currentUser.email)
```

This way, it will not be undefined.

Furthermore, there is no `restricted` prop in the `Route` component of `react-router`, in the v6.

I hope it solves your issue, otherwise please provide a reproducible example, so it is easier to locate the issue you are facing.

Comment: Thank you for your response but, If the user still remains undefined. So even when i put the correct email and pass and press submit i get redirected to the sign in again because the current user is never defined

Comment: Maybe because there is a typo in onAuthStateChanged?
I would rather write it like this:
onAuthStateChanged((auth, user) => setCurrentUser(user))
Are you sure you are getting a not undefined user there ?